# How to append pipe delimiter in string array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I've array of string in python, I'm iterating over the loop each value and trying to append ('|') symbol using below code. But its not appending as expected

```
result_list = []
new_value = 'iek,33833,,sdfd,lope'
my_list = ['abc,1234,,ickd,sold', 'yeje,38393,,dkdi,eole', 'euei,38393,,idkd,dikd']

for val in my_list:
  result_list.append(val + '|')

res = result_list.append(new_value) + '|')
print res
```

I'm trying to print the list of string including new string at last. But its giving me below error:

**TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list**

Sample output:

```
abc,1234,,ickd,sold|yeje,38393,,dkdi,eole|euei,38393,,idkd,dikd|iek,33833,,sdfd,lope|
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This will directly give you the result.

```
'|'.join(my_list) + '|'
```

Comment: That won't add `|` to the end.

Comment: this puts '|' in between  all the items, if you need at the end also, you can use '|'.join(my_list) + '|' or the below answer by andrew_reece

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to add `|`, then `join()`:

```
''.join([x+'|' for x in my_list])

# abc,1234,,ickd,sold|yeje,38393,,dkdi,eole|euei,38393,,idkd,dikd|
```

Simply using `'|'.join()` won't get you the final `|` you require.

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate, you can use join() to achieve this.

```
my_list = ['abc,1234,,ickd,sold', 'yeje,38393,,dkdi,eole', 'euei,38393,,idkd,dikd']

print '|'.join(my_list)
```

**output**:

`abc,1234,,ickd,sold|yeje,38393,,dkdi,eole|euei,38393,,idkd,dikd`

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. I'm trying to add new string into the existing array but its giving me an error. I've update my cost. could you please help

Comment: @learnjquery what is the error you're getting ? can you update it in question

Comment: I'm getting this error - TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: You have to append to existing list i.e. my_list and not string. check if it works.

Comment: No.. I don't want to append in my_list because result_list contains new formatted value which contains pipe delimiter and I want to add one more string which is new_value with pipe delimiter at end

Answer (score 0):

```
result_list = []
my_list = ['abc,1234,,ickd,sold', 'yeje,38393,,dkdi,eole', 'euei,38393,,idkd,dikd']

for val in my_list:
    result_list.append(str(val)+"|")
    # result_list.append()

print ''.join(result_list)
```

Comment: Thanks Rana. I'm trying to add some new value on my existing string array after iterating my list. But its giving me concatenation list error. I've update my post. Can you please me to fix this

Comment: In for loop use for val in my_list:
   ...:     result_list.append(val)
   ...:     result_list.append('|')
then if you want to new_value use result_list.append(new_value) then result_list.append('|'), it will be ok. thanks